# Euler and Hamilton graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

i would like to know  about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPaH.jpg). If it is Euler and Hamilton. As i see because it is $u_0$ unti $u_{19}$ it isn't Euler. Also, it is Hamilton because if we *erase* the edges we see it. Is this right or wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see a lot of labels, but I don't know what they mean. Anyway, do you know about the relation between Euler walks and vertices of odd degree? Can you see how to produce a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph?

Comment: yes i know ,but because i have different aspect of view with another .Please let me know if i am right about what i wrote up ,thanks )

Comment: I mean if i am right about this graph that it isnt Euler and it is Hamilton

Comment: @GerryMyerson so is this graph Hamilton and it isnt Euler?

Comment: If you can produce a Hamiltonian cycle in it, then the graph is Hamiltonian, no matter what anyone else (including me) might say. And if you know how Euler walks relate to vertices of odd degree, then you know whether the graph has an Euler walk, no matter what anyone else might say. So write up your convincing reasoning, citing well-established results, and you don't need me to tell you whether you are correct. But you have to write something more convincing that "it is $u_0$ until $u_{19}$" as I have no idea what that means, and I don't know what "if we erase the edges we see it" means.

Comment: On this graph we have verticles u0,u1,u,2,u3,u4,u5 until u19 so is odd that means it isn't Euler graph,because if it was Euler graph it must be even 20.Hamilton it must have degree 2 in the end , if we remove  the edges from the graph.Now ?@GerryMyerson

Comment: Nope, I'm not convinced by your proof that the graph has no Euler walk – I'm not even convinced that that's what you are trying to prove. "so is odd" – I don't understand what exactly is odd. If what you have done is to show that one particular walk doesn't use all the edges, that doesn't prove there is no walk that doesn't use all the edges. Anyway, for the third time, I'll ask you: do you know how Euler walks relate to vertices of odd degree? (do you know what an Euler walk is?) I don't know what "Hamilton it must have degree 2 in the end" means, and I don't know what edges you remove.

Comment: I think you had better start by writing down what you mean by "Euler" and what you mean by "Hamilton", since at this point I'm not sure you and I are even talking about the same things.

Comment: hamilton when it must be passing from all verticles and euler from all edges

Comment: Well, that's a good start. But why be so elliptical – are you paying by the word? I'd say, a graph is Hamiltonian if there's a path using each vertex exactly once; Eulerian, if there's a path using each edge exactly once. Now, can you engage with the rest of my comments?